# simple material cost calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to code a calculator which will give me a cost per square metre.

At the moment, I have the calculator working and producing a cost for the square meterage, however, what I want to try and do is have if statements, so that if the area comes back less than 15 m², the cost is worked out (area * 2000) and if the area comes back more than 15 m² it is worked out as (area star * 1750)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is currently

```js
function calculateCost() {
  var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
  var depth = document.getElementById("depth").value;
  var area = width * depth;
  var totalCost = area * 2000
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total cost: £" + totalCost;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Width in Metres: <input type="text" id="width"><br> Depth in Metres: <input type="text" id="depth"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateCost()">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var totalCost = area * 2000
```

write

```
var totalCost = area * (area <= 15 ? 2000 : 1750);
```

Now you will have price = area * 2000 for area less or equal than 15, and discount for higher areas.

Comment: Since Sam appears to be a beginner, I think it's worth pointing out that you're using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) here which has the syntax `condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`.

Answer (score 1):

A few answers were giving using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which were short and succinct, but I would argue they're not the most readable.

Effectively, you have a number (be it 2000 or 1750) that you need to multiply your the area with to get your total cost. You could start off by giving this a name. Say, `costMultiplier`.

We can assign it with the value 2000 to begin with (which assumes the area is                         less than 15m<sup>2</sup>).

```js
var costMultiplier = 2000;
```

Now, you just need to check if the area is greater than 15m<sup>2</sup>. And if it is, you update `costMultiplier` accordingly.

```js
if (area > 15) {
    costMultiplier = 1750;
}
```

Finally, you can update your `totalCost` like this

```js
var totalCost = area * costMultiplier
```

If there are any other conditions under which the cost multiplier might change, you could just add an `else if` branch to the if statement.

Comment: Thank you. I want to try and use your method. I am a newbie, really want to learn. I have tried to use else if conditions. something not right however. this is my code.

Comment: <script>
function calculateCost() {
  var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
  var depth = document.getElementById("depth").value;
  var area = width * depth;
  var costMultiplier = 2975;

 if (area  >29) {
    costMultiplier = 2650;
}

else if (area > 49) {
    costMultiplier = 2050;
}

 else if (area  > 39) {
    costMultiplier = 2362;
}


  var totalCost = area * costMultiplier
 
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total cost: £" + totalCost;
}
</script>

Comment: The issue you're facing is that your if/else statements are ordered wrong. First you're checking if area > 29, otherwise you're checking if area > 49? But if it's not greater than 29 then it would surely not be greater than 49, so the other statements are unreachable. So start with the largest value first. Then continue with the second largest and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to add a condition on the area value:

```js
function calculateCost() {
  var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
  var depth = document.getElementById("depth").value;
  var area = width * depth;
  var totalCost = (area < 15) ? area * 2000 : area * 1750;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total cost: £" + totalCost;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Width in Metres: <input type="text" id="width"><br> Depth in Metres: <input type="text" id="depth"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateCost()">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```